# Select rows where count of grouped data =2

Tags: sql, count, group-by

I have to get the users, which appear at least two weeks before and after the given date. So lets say I have data:

```
 userName    date  week 
 user1  27 10 2011  44
 user1  27 10 2011  44 
 user1  27 10 2011  44 
 user2  21 04 2011  17 
 user2  29 04 2011  17 
 user2  02 05 2011  19 
 user2  03 05 2011  19 
 user2  16 05 2011  21
 user2  23 05 2011  22 
 user3  06 01 2011  24 
 user3  14 05 2011  25 
 user3  20 05 2011  26 
 user3  27 05 2011  27
```

and I need to get the results first grouped by user and week, then I need to count how many weeks the user appears before (lets say week 20) and after, and then select only ones who appears at least 2 weeks before and after, so in my case I would get the result

```
user2
```

Unfortunately I cannot create viewTable because of the database restrictions. this query is giving me only the first part of the results, data grouped by user and week, but I have no idea how to count grouped data:

```
SELECT   username, 
         min(a.actionDate) as date, 
         datepart(wk,a.actionDate) as week 
FROM     Table1 a           
GROUP BY username , 
         datepart(wk,amd.actionDate)
```

thanks for any help.

Comment: What is the RDBMS please? Oracle? SQL Server? PostgreSQL? MySQL? SQLite? Other?

Answer (score 0):

To return users which have date records at least two weeks before and two weeks after a specified date, try:

```
select username
from Table1
group by username
having datediff(wk, min(actiondate), @date) >= 2 and 
       datediff(wk, @date, max(actiondate)) >= 2
```

Comment: I tried your code, which looks pretty simple, but it doesnt give the desired results. The one side 'having datediff(wk, min(actiondate), @date) >= 2' is working and filter the users haveing records at least two weeks, but if I add the second part after and 'datediff(wk, @date, max(actiondate)) >= 2
' it again gives me all the users, dont understand why?

Comment: What value did you assign to @date?

Comment: I assign the date, fro example '10 05 2011', the date which is in the week 20. I think the problem is with HAVING one statement AND another statement. because if I run one by one they both give me correct results, but how to join them ?

Comment: With the data supplied, if I run the query with both having conditions for @date 10 May 2011 then I get user2 and user3; this is because the first record for user3 in the example data is 6 Jan 2011 - if I change the date for that record to be 6 May 2011 then I only get user2. I am using SQLServer 2008 - which RDBMS are you using?

Comment: I am using the same, Sql Server 2008. I will try again, but as I told when I run them together, the result is just according to the first condition...

Comment: I finally managed to do that with INTERSECT function. But at the end I realized that it doesn't give me what I want. It counts the weeks from @date till the latest action date, while I want to know how many weeks the action was performed. do you have any suggestions? thanks